# Why segmentation fault occur while using pointer variable?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to read the paragraph using `scanf()` function in `C`.
So, First I tried the below code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char Input[100];
printf("Please give the paragraph\n");
scanf("%[^EOF]\n",Input );
printf("\n\n%s\n\n",Input);
return 1;
}
```

It's working fine, it get the paragraph of input from `stdin` and print it.
Then I tried the same thing with pointer like given below,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char *Input;
printf("Please give the paragraph\n");
scanf("%[^EOF]\n",Input );
printf("\n\n%s\n\n",Input);
return 1;
}
```

This code also get the input and print the output properly.
But it throw the `segmentation fault error while the program terminating.`
So, I need to know why the error occur while terminating?

If the pointer doesn't point any memory means, How the `printf()` is printing the given input, and from where it is printing?

Thanks.

Comment: Because the pointer is uninitalised. It contains garbage so you are telling `scanf` to write to a garbage location. And the fact that it outputs "properly" does not mean everything is fine. It just means you were lucky..this time. It can produce wrong results as well as crashing at any time. This is called Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: It's not the printing that's the problem; it's the reading.  You don't know where the data was placed because the pointer points to indeterminate space — you have to allocate space.  When you used an array, you supplied space.  When you use an uninitialized pointer, you don't.

Comment: `scanf("%[^EOF]\n",Input )`  -- I suggest reading the documentation for scanf instead of guessing

Comment: Incidentally, the `%[^EOF]` conversion probably doesn't do what you expect, and the trailing newline is definitely bad news.

Comment: May I know, Why I got down vote?

Comment: @Ganapathy Did your compiler give you a warning? Did you enable all of its warnings?

Comment: Yes I enabled the warnings, But it doesn't gave any warning while compiling

Comment: just out of curiosity, which c compiler are you using? And you should have a good C book at hand, read it thoroughly at least few times with experimenting, its going to be good for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Input` is a pointer to nothing in particular and has no value in particular, passing its value to `scanf` makes no sense. Assign it a value first -- make it point to something -- and then you can use it to tell `scanf` where to store things.